# A positive Bézout's identity

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

*Question*: Is the following statement true?

*Statement*: Let $a, b \ge 1$ be coprime numbers. Then $\exists N \ge 0 $ $\forall n \ge N$ $\exists u, v \ge 0$ with $n=au+bv$.
Let $N(a,b)$ be the smallest possible $N$. Then $N(a,b) = (a-1)(b-1)$.

Comment: Yes. If memory serves, $N-1$ is called the Frobenius number of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem.